# Concat two fields in JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I would like to have output like this with second IP:

`intranet.site.com : 59.89.8.8`

running this command

```bash
cat ./droplet_list.json | jq '.[] | .name , .networks.v4[].ip_address'
```

I have got

```
"intranet.site.com"
"10.136.95.40"
"59.89.8.8"
"57.23.3.1"
```

I was trying run:

```bash
cat ./droplet_list.json | jq '.[] | .name , .networks.v4[].ip_address[1]'
```

and  got the error

> ```
> "intranet.site.com"
> jq: error (at <stdin>:36035): Cannot index string with number
> ```

My JSON file

```json
[
  {
    "id": 106,
    "name": "intranet.site.com",
    "networks": {
      "v4": [
        {
          "ip_address": "10.136.95.40",
          "netmask": "255.255.0.0",
          "gateway": "10.136.0.1"
        },
        {
          "ip_address": "59.89.8.8",
          "netmask": "255.255.240.0",
          "gateway": "159.0.0.1"
        },
        {
          "ip_address": "57.23.3.1",
          "netmask": "255.255.252.0",
          "gateway": "157.0.0.1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `+` to concatenate the strings:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | .name + ": " + .networks.v4[].ip_address'
```

```json
intranet.site.com: 10.136.95.40
intranet.site.com: 59.89.8.8
intranet.site.com: 57.23.3.1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uYlBjJaLe1R)

You may also give the `.v4` array specific indices (instead of iterating over all of its items with `[]`):

```bash
jq - '.[] | .name + ": " + .networks.v4[1].ip_address'
```

```json
intranet.site.com: 59.89.8.8
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M2bPLcDGyfP)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using **`map`** along with **`+`** operator such as

```bash
jq -r 'map(.name + ": " + .networks.v4[].ip_address)[]' yourfile.json
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vRwuTpFZIeW)</kbd>